# sticky sessions in nginx-ingress-controller not working

Tags: kubernetes

I'm diving in to an issue with an existing kubernetes cluster, non EKS , setup on AWS.   We're trying to get sticky session support enabled, and I just can't get it working.   I've followed the docs and no luck.   Here's where I'm at now:

I've made these changes to our helm templates (both with and without the nginx prefix at the front of the annotation) . I haven't figured out how to check what version of the nginx-ingress-controller we're using so I've tried both and I know that the annotation has changed back in Dec of 17.

```
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
```

Deployed the changes and when I describe the ingress I can see it was deployed by describing the ingress (again, with and without the nginx prefix).   I really don't think this part is right, because examples I've seen is that everything before the / for the sticky annotations shouldn't be there, yet here they are.

```
Annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity:             cookie
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash:  sha1
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name:  route
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                nginx
```

But when I do a curl request I can see the cookie is not going to be set:

```
curl -I  https://test.com/hello
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx/1.11.3
date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 20:26:37 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
etag: W/"93a23971a914e5eacbf0a8d25154cda3"
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
x-request-id: fc91644f-a4b6-475b-9fb5-ccabe0551038
x-runtime: 0.006894
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains; preload
vary: Origin
```

Again, I have tested with and without the nginx. prefix for the sticky annotations and there has been no change, so I must be missing something.

Comment: Think I may have found out the issue.   Finally tracked down the pod running for the ingress, and looks like we are running 0.8.3 which I don't think had the sticky annotations, introduced in 0.9.

Comment: Now the question is how to update it, that I am still trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my old question that was unanswered.  My problem was I needed to specify the full annotation.  It required the nginx prefix

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity:             cookie
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash:  sha1
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name:  route
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed a different ingress controller from here :- https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

After installing the ingress controller from this link https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/ session stickiness worked fine for me.

YAML file I have used from here:- https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/ingress.yaml

To work with the domain name used in the above YAML file I added an entry in /etc/hosts file.

Comment: The links might answer the question but they also can become invalid making your answer useless. So please add the relevant details here to prevent your answer from becoming invalid.

Comment: Here actually link matters because I spent 2 days to find out why session stickiness is not working for me then I found out that the Nginx controller I installed is not the correct one.